# Gradle error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found

Tags: ionic-framework, gradle, build, ionic4

I removed and re-added the platform for clearing cache, Now I am getting the following error.

```
My ionic info:

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.0.2 (C:\Users\AH-KHAN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.6.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.8
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0
   native-run  : 0.2.5

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 8.1
```

I already tried:

- Changing com.android.support:support-v4:27+
- Adding gradle release plugin
- Cleaning and Rebuilding
- Add another platform android version
- Adding app_id and app_name in strings.xml

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > Failed to execute aapt

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more l
    og output.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 10s
    cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    C:\Users\AH-KHAN\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\5ea1ced35ab01cfb796d6
    0df5a71d20d\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings
     not found.

    C:\Users\AH-KHAN\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\5ea1ced35ab01cfb796d6
    0df5a71d20d\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

    C:\Users\AH-KHAN\Desktop\bawar\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResou
    rces\merged.dir\values\values.xml:265: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

    C:\Users\AH-KHAN\Desktop\bawar\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResou
    rces\merged.dir\values\values.xml:265: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
    error: failed linking references.

    Failed to execute aapt
    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
            at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
            at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidR
    esources.java:551)
            at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidRes
    ources.java:285)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:1
    09)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor414.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
            at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskActi
    on.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.
    execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.
    execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTa
    skExecuter.java:122)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.e
    xecute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.e
    xecute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationE
    xecutor.java:197)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecu
    tor.java:107)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteA
    ctionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(Execute
    ActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActions
    TaskExecuter.java:70)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTask
    Executer.java:63)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(Res
    olveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExec
    uter.java:58)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmpt
    ySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(Reso
    lveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWit
    hNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExec
    uter.java:54)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMo
    stOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchException
    TaskExecuter.java:34)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(Defau
    ltTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.e
    xecute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.e
    xecute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationE
    xecutor.java:197)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecu
    tor.java:107)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(Def
    aultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(Def
    aultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(Def
    aultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(Defa
    ultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(Defau
    ltTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(Defau
    ltTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.
    java:625)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecut
    ionPlan.java:580)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTask
    PlanExecutor.java:99)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPo
    licy.java:63)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryI
    mpl.java:55)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.and
    roid.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79
    )
            at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
            ... 47 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 er
    ror: check logs for details
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79
    )
            at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(Queueab
    leAapt2.java:179)
            at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2$$Lambda$444/1426803296.run(Unknown So
    urce)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            ... 1 more
    Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
            at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:4
    63)
            at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
            at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
            at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > Failed to execute aapt

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more l
    og output.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 10s
    [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

            cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

            Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: try delete or move resource folder and copy from the new project then build again

Comment: Regenerate your Icons and Splash screens in resources folder.

Comment: I regenerated all resources with ionic cordova resources.
The output was:

[cordova-res] Generated 18 resources for android
[cordova-res] Generated 45 resources for ios
[cordova-res] Wrote to config.xml
But no effect

Comment: Isolating your error to the changes I've made to you question leads me to a search of `ionic 4 fontVariationSettings`. There seems to be lots of results but digging through them is no fun so I'm passing this back to you to look into.